# Is it possible to have mutually referential C++ templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

### The Problem

I have the following two struct declarations:

```
template <typename T>
struct Yin {
  T *m_ptr;
};

template <typename T>
struct Yang {
  T *m_ptr;
};
```

and I'd like to find `X` and `Y` such that I get something like this after substitution:

```
// Not real C++ syntax
struct Yin<X> {
  Yang<Y> *m_ptr;
}

struct Yang<Y> {
  Yin<X> *m_ptr;
};
```

But I'd like to do so without hard-coding `Yin` and `Yang` into one another's definitions, so `X` would be something like `Yin<Yang<Yin<Yang<...>>>>`.

I can do this without template arguments like:

```
struct Yin;
struct Yang;

struct Yin {
  Yang *m_ptr;
};

struct Yang {
  Yin *m_ptr;
};
```

But my real use-case is considerably more complex and I'd really like to make it generic. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this? Or maybe see something obvious that I'm missing?

I've tagged this question as `c++14` because I'm compiling the relevant code with clang  with `-std=c++1y` and I am happy to use any c++11/c++14 features to make this work.

### A would-be solution that doesn't compile.

Here is a solution that looks like it should work, but doesn't compile (and gives me useless error messages):

```
template <typename T>
struct Yin {
  T *m_ptr;
};

template <typename T>
struct Yang {
  T *m_ptr;
};

template <template <class> class A, template <class> class B>
struct knot {
  using type = A<typename knot<B, A>::type>;
};

template <template <class> class A, template <class> class B>
using Tie = typename knot<A, B>::type;

int main() {
  // foo.cc:13:39: error: no type named 'type' in 'knot<Yin, Yang>'
  //  using type = A<typename knot<B, A>::type>;
  //                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
  Tie<Yin, Yang> x;
}
```

Comment: Considering that the right `X` and `Y` would have infinite levels, I don't see how this can be possible without explicit specialization.

Comment: Almost, using an additional level of inheritance: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e5d8300be418a6e

Comment: @dyp nice! the inheretence is clever. edit: Eh.. I misunderstood. It doesn't quite work. It's close though!

Comment: I can't get it to actually use the types, only with this additional level of inheritance. However, I can make the types `foo` and `bar` compatible: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6c3c0a6a6391c56

Comment: Hmmm... @mortehu already posted this as an answer; don't know why he deleted it.

Comment: I got this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bcd9aa67b40df386, is this the right idea?  Probably want to add some SFINAE so it doesn't accidentally pick up false positives, but I think it's good...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## YES

Specialize Yin and Yang for when `T` is a template type and `void` is the template parameter, which causes `Yin<Yang<void>>` to point at a `Yang<Yin<void>>` and vice versa, but without any explicit reference to the other, so you can have as many of these types as you want. with only one specialization.

```
//special recursive case
template <template<class> class other>
struct Yin<other<void>> 
{
    other<Yin<void>> *m_ptr;
};

template <template<class> class other>
struct Yang<other<void>> 
{
    other<Yang<void>> *m_ptr;
};
```

However, these specializations kick in for any `template<void>` type, so we need to apply SFINAE with a type trait:

```
template<template<class> class T> struct is_yinyang : public std::false_type {};
template<> struct is_yinyang<Yin> : public std::true_type {}; 
template<> struct is_yinyang<Yang> : public std::true_type {}
```

Then comes this horrible part, which is absurdly complicated and ugly, and requires a pointless extra template parameter on the Yin/Yang types:

```
//here's Yin + Specialization
template <typename T, class allowed=void>
struct Yin {
    T *m_ptr;
};
template<> struct is_yinyang<Yin> : public std::true_type {};

template <template<class,class> class other>
struct Yin<other<void,void>,typename std::enable_if<is_yinyang<other>::value>::type>
{
    other<Yin<void,void>,void> *m_ptr;
};
```

Now Yin and Yang reference only themselves, and adding new recursive pointer types is trivial.  Proof of compilation here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47ecd31e7d48f617

"But wait!" You exclaim, then I have to duplicate all my members!  Not quite simply split `Yin` into a class with the members that are shared, and have it inherit from `Yin_specialmembers<T>`, which contains the members that need specialization.  Easy.

Comment: "But I'd like to do so without hard-coding Yin and Yang into one another's definitions"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I'm not sure if that applies to template specializations, we'll have to see what if anything the OP says.  I can't think of any other way.

Comment: In my real code, there are several classes that act "like a Yin" and several that act "like a Yang", and I want to be able to combine any of them. So, this method would require a lot of specializations.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Complaint addressed

Comment: @scpayson: It is now expanded to N types

Comment: Why did you remove the rebinder? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88e2595217aee535 (Though I'm not 100% sure if those specializations of `is_yinyang` can be placed after the rebinder)

Comment: @dyp: it was unnecessary and intimidating. I vaguely recall that it interfered with the SFINAE as well

Comment: Well I think it helps keeping `Yin` and `Yang` simple... there's none of the logic of rebinding present in that solution. Not sure where the problem with SFINAE is.

Comment: @dyp: OH! As I try to rewrite the code using a rebinder I see what the issue was.  I was using `rebinder` as a _generic type trait piece_.  Note that in my code `rebind<allocator<char>,int>::type` would have worked.  Whereas you're using it to implement the Yin/Yang metamagic.  I'll try what you're doing and see what I can accomplish.

Comment: Actually, yours already does what I thought couldn't be done!  That'll teach me to skim over metamagic code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  First, teach `Yin` and `Yang` how to accept an arbitrary mapping for the type they store:

```
template<class T>struct identity{using type=T;};

template <typename T, template<class>class Z=identity>
struct Yin {
  template<class U>using Z_t=typename Z<U>::type;
  Z_t<T> *m_ptr;
};

template <typename T, template<class>class Z=identity>
struct Yang {
  template<class U>using Z_t=typename Z<U>::type;
  Z_t<T> *m_ptr;
};
```

with a default of "just take `T`".

Then write a meta template type function that we can pass to `Yin` and `Yang`:

```
template<
  template<class, template<class>class>class Yin,
  template<class, template<class>class>class Yang
>
struct flopper {
  template<class T> struct flip {
    using type = Yang<T, flopper<Yang, Yin>::template flip>;
  };
};
```

which takes two things like `Yin` and `Yang` and switches which one it applies each time for its second argument.

And to test it:

```
using yin = Yin< void, flopper<Yin, Yang>::template flip >;
using yang = Yang< void, flopper<Yang, Yin>::template flip >;
yin a = {nullptr};
yang b = {&a};
```

we create the types, and [it compiles](http://ideone.com/QqgUjr).

Attempts to [clean up some of the syntax fail](http://ideone.com/Je8xVx) at least in that version of gcc.

Note that the type at infinity -- `void` above -- can be changed, and different types result.

In this case, there is **no** connecting between `Yin` and `Yang`, and beyond that mapping, nothing need be done to the two types in question.  The only connection is in the `flopper` meta template type function.  The mapping type function is even relatively agnostic to `Yin` and `Yang` -- I used their names, but did not have to.